# Does Safari 15.1 (15.1 on macOS and iOS 15.1) fix losing tabs opened in groups?

Tags: macos, ios, safari, data-synchronization, tabs

I had problems in Safari 15 (not 15.1) with tabs disappearing. Few times iPhone have different tabs opened in some groups and when it synced this group with Mac it basically overwritten what tabs I have - losing results of my research or other work.
I stopped using Safari after this and my question is - is it fixed in 15.1?

It would be great if someone could show some changelog that mention this particular case being fixed or example of some user that lost his tabs in Safari 15 but don't lose them anymore on Safari 15.1. Thanks

Comment: Why not just try it?

Comment: Because I don't want to lose my data again? I lost opened tabs. In 2021. Several times.

Comment: I still see this happening in 15.2 :-(

Comment: too bad, I really want to use Safari... :(